# Qt Widgets: Handle TAB-presses exclusively

Tags: qt, widget, focus, keypress

Following situation:

My UI has top-level tabs, that can contain multiple child widgets several levels deep. I want to use (CTRL-)TAB to navigate between those top-level tabs, and only for that.

I've overwritten the **keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent*)**-function for that purpose. This catches every keypress correctly EXCEPT for TAB. I assume this is because TAB is, by default, used to switch focus between all widgets on the screen (which I can observe).
Apparently this also happens before my function can catch the TAB press, so it never receives it.

How can I correct this behavior? My first idea was to loop through all of the widgets and set their **FocusPolicy** to **NoFocus**, but that seems too hacky and I'm not even sure whether it would work.

The second idea was to make sure that the **QTabWidget** containing the top-level tabs never loses its focus, so I can just utilize its built-in TAB-navigation. But there seems to be no way to force the focus on a single widget without wild hacks (like listening for the **focusChangedEvent** and then manually returning the focus to the QTabWidget...).

It feels like I'm going all wrong about this, can anyone help me out here?

*There's gotta be a better way!*

Comment: Sounds like a job for [event filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter). A code example, that doesn't behave like it should, could be useful to understand the problem better, and propose a specific solution.

Comment: The TAB presses don't get as far as the event filter. They're handled somewhere else and then discarded. That's the underlying issue.